# How to display unit after price on the checkout page

Tags: checkout

I sell products per different kind of units, like m2, bigbag etc. I would like to display the kind of unit after the price on the checkoutpage. What kind of code do I have to use to display the unit of that product?

I have circled in the screenshot what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

1. Add a custom attribute to your product that define the unit type
2. Edit app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
3. Modify the html accordingly and add code `echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('{attribute name here}');`

Comment: Do I have to include it with php tags like: <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('{attribute name here}');?> Or what is the code exactly. My custom attribute is "eenheid".

I use onepagecheckout. Do I have to add it also in the base? And if I want it on the cart page?